# Trigger click event by dispatchTouchEvent doesn't work?

Tags: android, touch-event, android-maps-v2

I want to make google map v2 infowindow to be a life view, so I wrap SupportMapFragment in custom RelativeLayout like this:

**R.layout.info_window:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.Amazing.GoogleMapV2.MapWrapperLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map_relative_layout">
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</com.Amazing.GoogleMapV2.MapWrapperLayout>
```

And I override dispatchTouchEvent, offset motionEvent location to infowindow view coordinate and then dispatchTouchEvent to infoWindow:
**MapWrapperLayout:**

```
public class MapWrapperLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    /**
     * Reference to a GoogleMap object
     */
    private GoogleMap map;

    /**
     * Vertical offset in pixels between the bottom edge of our InfoWindow
     * and the marker position (by default it's bottom edge too).
     * It's a good idea to use custom markers and also the InfoWindow frame,
     * because we probably can't rely on the sizes of the default marker and frame.
     */
    private int bottomOffsetPixels;

    /**
     * A currently selected marker
     */
    private Marker marker;

    /**
     * Our custom view which is returned from either the InfoWindowAdapter.getInfoContents
     * or InfoWindowAdapter.getInfoWindow
     */
    private View infoWindow;

    public MapWrapperLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MapWrapperLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MapWrapperLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Must be called before we can route the touch events
     */
    public void init(GoogleMap map, int bottomOffsetPixels) {
        this.map = map;
        this.bottomOffsetPixels = bottomOffsetPixels;
    }

    /**
     * Best to be called from either the InfoWindowAdapter.getInfoContents
     * or InfoWindowAdapter.getInfoWindow.
     */
    public void setMarkerWithInfoWindow(Marker marker, View infoWindow) {
        this.marker = marker;
        this.infoWindow = infoWindow;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Make sure that the infoWindow is shown and we have all the needed references
        if (marker != null && marker.isInfoWindowShown() && map != null && infoWindow != null) {
            // Get a marker position on the screen
            Point point = map.getProjection().toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());

            // Make a copy of the MotionEvent and adjust it's location
            // so it is relative to the infoWindow left top corner
            MotionEvent copyEv = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
            copyEv.offsetLocation(
                    -point.x + (infoWindow.getWidth() / 2),
                    -point.y + infoWindow.getHeight() + bottomOffsetPixels);
            Log.e("~~~~~~~~~~dispatchTouchEvent  copyEv", copyEv.toString());

            //Dispatch the adjusted MotionEvent to the infoWindow
            if (infoWindow.dispatchTouchEvent(copyEv)) {
                Log.e("infoWindow.dispatchTouchEvent(copyEv)", "True");
                Log.e("~~~~~~~~~~dispatchTouchEvent  point", point.toString());
                Log.e("~~~~~~~~~~dispatchTouchEvent  ev", ev.toString());
                Log.e("~~~~~~~~~~dispatchTouchEvent  copyEv", copyEv.toString());
                return true;
            }
        }
        // If the infoWindow consumed the touch event, then just return true.
        // Otherwise pass this event to the super class and return it's result
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

**R.layout.info_window:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="Title"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/snippet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="snippet"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" android:clickable="true" android:enabled="true" android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And MainActivity inflate R.layout.info_window and setOnClickListener to infoButton which is on the info_window:
**MainActivity:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
        private ViewGroup infoWindow;
        private TextView infoTitle;
        private TextView infoSnippet;
        private Button infoButton;
    //    private OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener infoButtonListener;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            final SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                    (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            final MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout =
                    (MapWrapperLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);
            final GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMap();

            // MapWrapperLayout initialization
            // 39 - default marker height
            // 20 - offset between the default InfoWindow bottom edge and it's content bottom edge
            mapWrapperLayout.init(map, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));

            // We want to reuse the info window for all the markers,
            // so let's create only one class member instance
            this.infoWindow = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
            this.infoTitle = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.infoSnippet = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
            this.infoButton = (Button)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.button);
            // Setting custom OnTouchListener which deals with the pressed state
            // so it shows up
    //        this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton,
    //                R.drawable.btn_normal, R.drawable.btn_pressed)
    //        {
    //            @Override
    //            protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
    //                // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the button
    //                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, marker.getTitle() + "'s button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //            }
    //        };
            this.infoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "~~~~~ Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                    // Setting up the infoWindow with current's marker info
                    infoTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                    infoSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
    //                infoButtonListener.setMarker(marker);

                    // We must call this to set the current marker and infoWindow references
                    // to the MapWrapperLayout
                    mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
                    return infoWindow;
                }
            });

            // Let's add a couple of markers
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(50.08, 14.43)));
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title("Prague")


   .snippet("Czech Republic")
                .position(new LatLng(50.08, 14.43)));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Paris")
                .snippet("France")
                .position(new LatLng(48.86,2.33)));

        Marker m = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("London")
                .snippet("United Kingdom")
                .position(new LatLng(51.51,-0.1)));
        m.showInfoWindow();
    }

    public static int getPixelsFromDp(Context context, float dp) {
        final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int)(dp * scale + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

These code act strange, button's onClick will be call when activity onResume() not immediate call,
But onTouch event is immediately call.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be related to this other issue.

[Runnable is posted successfully but not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083787/runnable-is-posted-successfully-but-not-run)

The problem is that in View.onTouchEvent ( MotionEvent event ) when the ACTION_UP event happens instead of just calling performClick() Android calls post() with a PerformClick runnable.  This runnable does not run because your view is not attached to the window.

To fix the problem simply add the view to the MapWrapperLayout.  You can even put it off screen so that it doesn't impact the look of the map.

```
public void setMarkerWithInfoWindow ( Marker marker, View infoWindow )
{
    this.marker = marker;

    if ( this.infoWindow != null )
    {
        this.removeView ( this.infoWindow );
    }
    this.infoWindow = infoWindow;

    // Force the view to render WAY off screen, so we don't actually see it.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
    params.leftMargin = 100000;

    this.addView ( infoWindow, params );
}
```