# Scaling the image to the size of the linear layout

Tags: android-layout, opencv, bitmap, scale

I have a mat object, which has image information used by openCV library for image processing. The mat object is basically a matrix. I need to scale this object to the size of the linear layout in which i need to display after converting it to Bitmap.

The steps would briefly be as follows:-
1. Get the height and width of the linear layout.
2. Scale the mat object to the width and height.
3. Convert the object to bitmap
4. Display the bitmap onto the linear layout

I do all this in the onStart method where the layout with and height is 0. I am failing in the first step.

How do i get the width and height.
Also Can i get the coordinates of the linear layout in onstart() method.

Kindly help

Crazy idea would be to display a dummy image first, get the layout width and height and then display the actual image....i am a beginner...

Comment: scaletype fitxy for the imageview.. did u try it.

Comment: i don't have an image view. I have an object , Mat object precisely. I need to scale the object to the width and height of the layout.

Comment: Mat objects are used in openCV. For image processing

Comment: Modified the question. Please go through it again

Comment: possible duplicate of [linearlayout not initialised in onStart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684066/linearlayout-not-initialised-in-onstart)

Comment: There's no need to talk about steps 2, 3 and 4. Your problem is on step 1, and we simply don't need to know the rest. Please simplify the question and erase the other parts (don't forget to get rid of the tags as well).

Answer (score 0):

Rather do it the other way,as shown below -

**i>** Convert the `Mat` image to `BitMap`. Here is the code for doing so -

```
Mat mat;
// Intialize mat
Bitmap bitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(mat, bitMap);
```

**ii>** In the layout file, use an `ImageView` in the `LineatLayout` and set the `layout_width` and `fill_height` to `match_parent`. This will use the whole linear layout. Here is the code for doing so -

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
    android:layout_width= "match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Don't forget to add `description` in `strings.xml`.

**iii>** Put the `Bitmap` image in the `LinearLayout`, as shown below -

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
```

Using this code, you will be able to display a `Mat` image in a `LinearLayout`.