# Adding nested views dynamically freezes the App

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I am building the app, which generates and adds view dynamically. I don't know in advance what views I need to create, these can be nested layouts or simple labels, etc, depending what comes back from web services.

Everything has been well so far until I started building really complex nested layouts .I have one case where I need to add about 11 levels of Layouts dynamically. When activity starts I display ProgressDialog(ring), while views are being generated. My problem is that with this complex structure ProgressDialog freezes while views are added. This is the code, which creates the view:

```
private class ViewCreator implements Runnable {

    public BackgroundTaskViewCreatedResponse delegate;
    private View mCreatedView;
    private ComponentDefinition mComponent;

    private ViewCreator(ComponentDefinition component){
        this.mComponent = component;
    }       

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (mComponent != null){
                mComponent.setLinkedData(model.getLinkedData());
                mCreatedView = componentCreator.createComponent(mComponent);
            }
        } finally {
            if (mCreatedView != null)
                delegate.processFinishTask(mCreatedView);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout, which has other views in it implements `BackgroundTaskViewCreatedResponse`, so, when view is ready, it will be added:

```
@Override
public void processFinishTask(final View createdView) {
    //((Activity)view.getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    mView.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mView.addView(createdView);
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see above, I have tried to call `runOnUiThread` call, but this blocks the UI thread completely while view hierarchy is being generated. At the same time `view.post` doesn't get called out of the box, so I have made some changes to views as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18377490/1889148). So, now my views are added, but my ProgressDialog is not running smoothly. It stops in a few occasions and then resumes. I've also tried using Android `AsyncTask`, but that gives the same effect as `runOnUiThread`

I am not very experienced with Threads, have been trying to fix this for a few days now. Please help.

Comment: `I am not very experienced with Threads` <= the you have to fix it ... but first use some profiling tool and check what takes most of the time ...

Comment: @Selvin: 
Thanks, 
I've already tried to use StrictMode and don't seem to have any policy violations. Currently trying to use this: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html.
Is there anything else you could suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsyncTask to do this/ Here is an example:

```
private class GenerateViews extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // SHOW THE SPINNER WHILE GENERATING VIEWS
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

         //CALL YOUR VIEW GENERATING METHOD HERE

         return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

        spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
}
```

You can make this class inside your class, if you want to. And then, you just call

```
new GenerateCalls.execute();
```

Comment: I've already tried to use it, thanks. It block threads even worse than what I have at the moment.

Comment: that's strange..well, if you find a way that does the trick, post your answer here. I'd like to know :)